# breaking while loop and doesn't print the result c#

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, while-loop, break

I'm a beginner in c# and I'm training on codeforces and SPOJ  to learning how to solve problems,
the problem with me is when the loop  is break doesn't print all the input it's just end the program without printing

please can someone tell me what is the mistake in these 2 codes that i write >

the Input:
1,2,88,42 ,99
Output:
1,2,88

```
class Program

 {

  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("please enter an integer number in two digits");

        int numbers;
        int[] array_num = new int[100];

        string nu = "";
        int i =1;
      
         while(i<100)
         {
             numbers = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
             nu += numbers;
             array_num[i] = numbers;
             

            if(array_num[i]<array_num[i-1])

            {
                Console.WriteLine("the numbers is " +nu+ "");
                break;
            }

            i++;
            
           
         }
       
       }

      }
```

and i do it in for loop and the same problem

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("please enter an integer number in two digits");

        int numbers;
        int[] array_num = new int[50];

        string nu = "";

        for (int i = 1; i <= array_num.Length; i++)
        {
            numbers = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            nu += numbers;
            array_num[i] = numbers;
           
            if (array_num[i] < array_num[i - 1])
            {

                Console.WriteLine("the number is " + nu + "");
                           
                break;
            }
           
        }

    }
```

what is the mistake?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is your expected result? `break` exits the loop, so you won't get any more lines printed. `continue` brings you to the next iteration is that's what you're trying to do?

Comment: Unclear. Do you want it to print the entire array - even the numbers after the one that satisfies the condition?

Comment: i need to end inputs with the if condition , so if the condition is true print the inputs and stop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to *"...the problem is when the loop is break doesn't print all the input it's just end the program..."*:

That's because after you breaked loop there is no more code to execute - so Console closes. You can add `Console.ReadKey()` or `Console.ReadLine()` at the end of `Main` method to keep Console opened after loop breaked. `Console.ReadKey()` would wait until you press any key, `Console.ReadLine()` would wait until you input something and press Enter (or just press Enter). Or in both ways Console will stay opened until you close it manually.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // ...
    for (int i = 1; i <= array_num.Length; i++)
    {
        // ...
        if (array_num[i] < array_num[i - 1])
        {
            Console.WriteLine("the number is " + nu + "");
            break;
        }
    }
    
    Console.ReadKey(); // Here Console will wait until you press any key and will stay opened
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help , i have another question there is another way to print the outputs and keeps the console open instead off (ReadKey)?

Comment: As I said in aswer, you can use `Console.ReadLine()`, it's a bit similar to `ReadKey()`. This to is simplest way to keep Console opened. Other ways are more specific or complicated and not preferred for common usage.

Comment: @leena almasnour mark answer as helpful if it solve or help to solve your question.

Comment: done, sorry I'm new here for asking questions i was just a viewer.